# Is there a way to optimise my Powershell function for removing pattern matches from a large file?

Tags: regex, powershell, optimization, powershell-4.0

I've got a large text file (~20K lines, ~80 characters per line).
I've also got a largish array (~1500 items) of objects containing patterns I wish to remove from the large text file. Note, if the pattern from the array appears on a line in the input file, I wish to remove the entire line, not just the pattern.

The input file is CSVish with lines similar to:

```
A;AAA-BBB;XXX;XX000029;WORD;WORD-WORD-1;00001;STRING;2015-07-01;;010;
```

The pattern in the array which I search each line in the input file for resemble the

```
XX000029
```

part of the line above.

My somewhat naïve function to achieve this goal looks like this currently:

```
function Remove-IdsFromFile {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
    [string]$BigFile,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
    [Object[]]$IgnorePatterns
  )

  try{
    $FileContent = Get-Content $BigFile
  }catch{
    Write-Error $_
  }

  $IgnorePatterns | ForEach-Object {
    $IgnoreId = $_.IgnoreId
    $FileContent = $FileContent | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch $IgnoreId }
    Write-Host $FileContent.count
  }
  $FileContent | Set-Content "CleansedBigFile.txt"
}
```

This works, but is *slow*.

How can I make it quicker?

Comment: Do you have a sample of ignore patterns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```psh
function Remove-IdsFromFile {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
        [string]$BigFile,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
        [Object[]]$IgnorePatterns
    )

    # Create the pattern matches
    $regex = ($IgnorePatterns | ForEach-Object{[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join "|"

    If(Test-Path $BigFile){
    $reader = New-Object  System.IO.StreamReader($BigFile)

    $line=$reader.ReadLine()
    while ($line -ne $null)
    {
        # Check if the line should be output to file
        If($line -notmatch $regex){$line | Add-Content "CleansedBigFile.txt"}

        # Attempt to read the next line. 
        $line=$reader.ReadLine()
    }

    $reader.close()

    } Else {
        Write-Error "Cannot locate: $BigFile"
    }
}
```

`StreamReader` is one of the preferred methods to read large text files. We also use regex to build pattern string to match based on. With the pattern string we use `[regex]::Escape()` as a precaution if regex control characters are present. Have to guess since we only see one pattern string.

If `$IgnorePatterns` can easily be cast as strings this should working in place just fine. A small sample of what `$regex` looks like would be:

```
XX000029|XX000028|XX000027
```

If `$IgnorePatterns` is populated from a database you might have less control over this but since we are using regex you might be able to reduce that pattern set by *actually using* regex (instead of just a big alternative match) like in my example above. You could reduce that to `XX00002[7-9]` for instance.

I don't know if the regex itself will provide an performance boost with 1500 possibles. The `StreamReader` is supposed to be the focus here. However I did sully the waters by using `Add-Content` to the output which does not get any awards for being fast either (*could* use a stream writer in its place).

**Reader and Writer**

I still have to test this to be sure it works but this just uses `streamreader` and `streamwriter`. If it does work better I am just going to replace the above code.

```
function Remove-IdsFromFile {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
        [string]$BigFile,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
        [Object[]]$IgnorePatterns
    )

    # Create the pattern matches
    $regex = ($IgnorePatterns | ForEach-Object{[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join "|"

    If(Test-Path $BigFile){
        # Prepare the StreamReader
        $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($BigFile)

        #Prepare the StreamWriter
        $writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter("CleansedBigFile.txt")

        $line=$reader.ReadLine()
        while ($line -ne $null)
        {
            # Check if the line should be output to file
            If($line -notmatch $regex){$writer.WriteLine($line)}

            # Attempt to read the next line. 
            $line=$reader.ReadLine()
        }

        # Don't cross the streams!
        $reader.Close()
        $writer.Close()

    } Else {
        Write-Error "Cannot locate: $BigFile"
    }
}
```

You might need some error prevention in there for the streams but it does appear to work in place.

Comment: I thought about making it into one enormous regex, but wasn't sure that would work properly. I'll try your solution and see though.
Also, I don't mind building the output up in memory - I'll be running this on a server with 128GB of RAM - I'm not scared of running out of memory ;)

Comment: Just tested the first version, albeit by just appending $line to an array variable and then doing one set-content at the end. *Orders* of magnitude faster than the original version. Awesome - thank you!